# Object Detection?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, object-detection

I need to detect objects from an image taken by the camera in Android, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to do so. Many of the tutorials I found online are about Face detection or use machine learning to detect objects of a certain shape, however, I need a method for general objects. Is it necessary to use OpenCV, and/or would ARCore be useful in this scenario? Or is there another API that could be used with Android for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement with OpenCV much easier than other image processing libraries. There is no general method for all objects. However, you can start digging from the image segmentation to create your own custom image transformation algorithms.

https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07-image-segmentation.html

Answer (score 0):

There are trained models for object detection. You can use one of them. I suggest exploring this. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Best regards.